# If you calculate and then get power supply by the battery 12V 6W. But total power dissipated in the two resistors in 3W.

Tags: circuit-analysis

Question 1: In the network of fig-2 shown in below. If you calculate and then get power supply by the battery 12V 6W. But total power dissipated in the two resistors in 3W. 
Where has the balance (rest) power 3W gone? 
[image]

Comment: If you show how you get those results, then people will help.

Comment: And can you edit your question to state what the numbers beside the lower battery are supposed to be. Is it 12 V or something else?

Comment: Its 12V exactly.

Comment: This question could use some improvement but it's not so bad as to be worth -3 votes

Answer (score 2):

> Where has the balance (rest) power 3W gone?

[image]

Through the 12 volt battery flows 0.5 amps and this indeed represents a load of 6 watts. The voltage across the resistors is 6 volts and this is a power of only 3 watts. However, the 6 volt battery is being "charged" by a power of 3 watts.

So, to answer your question, the 6 volt battery is consuming 3 watts and if it is a rechargeable type then it is being charged. If it isn't a rechargeable type then it will get hotter due to the 3 watts of power heating it up.